# JavaScript Functions and Switch statements. Can Somebody guide me on this?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

Ok, so me and a friend are making a JS game together. It's a God Game kinda thing in which the user uses resources to build houses and other buildings. IT IS IN VERY EARLY DEVELOPMENT!

I use variables as grid references, so they can be set to a certain building. e.g.:

`var OneOne = none`

So the grid would look like this:

- OneOne, OneTwo, OneThree
- TwoOne, TwoTwo, TwoThree
- ThreeOne, ThreeTwo, ThreeThree

My problem is somewhere in the building phase, I use a function called `Build(type, loc)` that  is used for adding a building to the map. I do this with a switch statement that looks at the `loc` parameter and sets the corresponding grid reference to the value of the building. So if `this.loc === OneOne`, then `OneOne = this.type`.

The desired outcome of this script is to set OneOne to WoodHut.

In Theory, if you were to print off the grid line by line, having just done `Build(WoodHut, OneOne)`, you should get something like:

- WoodHut, none, none
- none, none, none
- none, none, none

But this will not work! I can't really figure out why this isn't working...
The REAL outcome i get is:

- none, none, none
- none, none, none
- none, none, none

Here is my source code: [JS](http://pastebin.com/zehg73Ci)

And the HTML I use to run the script and the functions: [HTML](http://pastebin.com/Ly6Se8Ye)

Please have a read through them and spot my error! A hint or tutorial would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Hint: Use arrays in place of the variables, as Tomás recommended.

Comment: These do not answer my question, my problem is in the Build function, not variables...

Comment: @Corwen Nobody knows what your question even *is*. You need to provide actual v. desired output, don't make people chase down your code, etc.

Comment: Okay Adam. Could you expand on this please? Or send me a link to a tutorial of some kind? Thanks

Comment: changed the question slightly...

Comment: OneOne = type ... isn't it supposed to be OneOne = type; ? Including the ";"?

Comment: @AlejandroIván I thought the same at first but I have looked up the syntax of a switch statement, and mine matches all examples I found.

Comment: why return false; for the default case but no return of any kind for other cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var OneOne = none;
var OneTwo = none;
var OneThree = none;
var OneFour = none;
var OneFive = none;

var TwoOne = none;
var TwoTwo = none;
var TwoThree = none;
var TwoFour = none;
var TwoFive = none;

var ThreeOne = none;
var ThreeTwo = none;
var ThreeThree = TownHall;
var ThreeFour = none;
var ThreeFive = none;

var FourOne = none;
var FourTwo = none;
var FourThree = none;
var FourFour = none;
var FourFive = none;

var FiveOne = none;
var FiveTwo = none;
var FiveThree = none;
var FiveFour = none;
var OneFive = none;
```

Don't do that. Use arrays instead. Below is a way to do this with an array of arrays; e.g. a matrix.

```
var tiles = [];
var rowCount = 5; // put as many as you like
var columnCount = 5; // put as many as you like

// Assign the none string to all tiles.
for (var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
{
    tiles[r] = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < columnCount; c++)
    {
        var currentRow = tiles[r];
        currentRow[c] = "--none--";
    }
}

// Now access FourTwo (row 4, column 2). Remember arrays are 0-based.
console.log(tiles[3][1]);

// Assign something to FiveThree
tiles[4][2] = "WoodHut"
```

Comment: You need to initialize `tiles[r] = []` as the first statement of your 'for (var r' loop.